# using vue component but appear blank

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

is this the right way to include a vue component?

```
new Vue({
  render: (h) => h(App)
})
  .component("v-select", vSelect)
  .$mount("#app");
```

I tried to use [vue-select](https://vue-select.org/guide/install.html) but seeing a blank screen https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-goodall-judt9?file=/src/main.js:164-254

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To register vue component, use this way

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";

import vSelect from "vue-select";
import "vue-select/dist/vue-select.css";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

//Here register v-select component
Vue.component("v-select", vSelect);

new Vue({
  render: (h) => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```